# Variable availability, function declaration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have issue with accessing variable defined in my Angular project. I am complete newbie but please have a patience.
My project looks like this:

app.component.html:

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor='let var1 of Fcomponent' >{{var1}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project';
  }
```

variables1.component.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class Variables1Service{
  Fcomponent: number[]=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
}
```

variables1.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})
export class Variables1Service{
  Fcomponent: number[]=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Variables1Service } from './variables1.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [Variables1Service],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

Cannot GET /.
Error: src/app/app.component.html:3:27 - error TS2339:Property 'Fcomponent' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'.

3   <li *ngFor='let var1 of Fcomponent' >{{var1}}

How to make it working?

Comment: You get this error because there is more than one component.ts file referencing app.component.html.

So either you should move the Fcomponent array to the app.component.ts or if you want to keep it separated for some reason you can create a class without @Compnent decorator and instantiate the class in the app.component.ts.

Comment: `Fcomponent` doesn't exist in your app.component.ts file. Actually it resides in your variables1.component.ts file. Now if you want to access the Fcomponent in your app component if you move it to your service file and add the service as a dependency in your app component.

Comment: I updated project as pointed and now encountered one additional road block. Any hints how to go further?

Comment: Could you advise how and where to add function which shuffle that Fcomponent array?  function shuffle(array){
    for (let i=array.length-1;i>0;i--) {
      let j=Math.floor(Math.random()*(i+1));
      [array[i],array[j]]=[array[j],array[i]];
    }
    return array;

Answer (score 1):

Inside app.component.ts under:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'project';
```

there was a need to add the following code:

```
  private variables1Service:Variables1Service;

  constructor (){
    this.variables1Service=new Variables1Service();
  }

  get Fcomponent() {
    return this.variables1Service.Fcomponent;
  }
```

And all started working corectly.